# Determine calling convention at compile time

Tags: c++, c

Is there a way to determine which calling conventions are used at compile time, either via predefined macros or with some other trickery?

Or does it just boil down to platform detection?

The goal here is to detect the *default*, non-variadic, non-thiscall, undecorated function calling convention used by the compiler in order to write machine code that can correctly call into such functions given just a function pointer instead of enforcing the bound functions are decorated properly.

Comment: @PaulR Woops, case of the mondays. Thanks :)

Comment: On Windows at least the symbol names are generated differently so if you get the convention wrong it shouldn't link. If that's what you're worried about, things breaking unexpectedly at runtime?

Comment: This is very dependent on compiler and operating system, as different compiler could have different calling conventions on one OS, of the same compiler could have different calling conventions on different OS's.

Comment: @Rup Perhaps it is indeed an X-Y problem, but I want to write some machine code that calls into C portably with the correct calling convention. I understand there are a few used on any given machine, and that they can be changed given directives, but I want to be able to detect and enforce the calling convention used by default for non-variadic and non-thiscall functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right - hence why I'm asking if I can detect the default convention at compile time :)

Comment: Not in a standardized and common way. You have to learn it for every compiler/OS combination you're targeting. :)

Comment: Platform is not sufficient, since the usual calling conventions can be explicitly overridden. So some more infos about your intentions would be helpful

Comment: @Christophe added some context to the Q.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yargh, I figured as much. Mind making an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Run, don't walk, over to http://sourceware.org/libffi/ .  They've done most if not all the work you need to do.